# How to update my score text correctly in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I have my `score` variable updating in my Archery game. However, I cannot get the score to update correctly. Every time it updates, the new text just pastes over the old text.

I have tried it inside of the `getMedal()` function, outside of the `getMedal()` function, inside the `render()` function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Video Game</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Configurations for the physics engine
    var physicsConfig = {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: false //CHANGE THIS TO TRUE TO SEE LINES
        }
    }
    //Configurations for the game itself
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: physicsConfig,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update,
            render: render
        }
    };
    //Start the game
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {   
        //Images
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/images/sky.png');
        this.load.image('target', 'assets/images/target.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/images/ground.png');
        this.load.image('arrow', 'assets/images/arrow.png');
        this.load.image('gold_medal', 'assets/images/goldmedal.png');
        this.load.image('silver_medal', 'assets/images/silvermedal.png');
        this.load.image('bronze_medal', 'assets/images/bronzemedal.png');
        //Spritesheets
        this.load.spritesheet('archer', 'assets/spritesheets/archer_sprites.png', {frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128});
        this.load.spritesheet('rings', 'assets/spritesheets/rings_sprite.png', {frameWidth: 320, frameHeight: 320});
        //Audio
        this.load.audio('arrow_shot', 'assets/sounds/arrow_shooting.mp3');
    }
    function create ()
    {   
        //Load all the images that won't move
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
        this.add.image(210, 200, 'ground');

        //Create the archer/player
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 410, 'archer');
        this.player.setBounce(0.2);
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        //Shooting animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'shoot',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('archer', {start : 0, end: 4}),
            frameRate: 20,
            repeat: 0
        });

        //Rings animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'rings_anim',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('rings', {start : 0, end : 69}),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: 0
        })
        //Play the animation on start
        this.rings = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 40, 'rings');
        this.rings.anims.play('rings_anim', true);

        //Create the target
        this.target = this.physics.add.sprite(530, 365, 'target');
        this.target.setSize(115, 95).setOffset(70, 130); //TARGET HITBOX
        this.target.enableBody = true;
        this.target.setImmovable();

        //Create an array for arrows for later
        this.arrows = [];

        //Create an array for medals for later
        this.medals = [];

        //Get keypresses
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        //Assign input for spacebar
        this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

        //Play sound when the arrow is shot
        this.arrowSound = this.sound.add('arrow_shot');

        //Make the arrows collide with the target
        this.physics.add.collider(this.arrows, this.target)

    }
    function update ()
    {   
        //Declare constants for movement
        const playerMoveAmt = 200;
        const arrowMoveAmt = 1500;
        this.player.setDrag(2000);

        //Declare variables for the score
        var score = 0;
        var scoreBoard;

        //Add the scoreboard in
        //Scoreboard
        scoreBoard = this.add.text(440, 40, "SCORE:0", 
        {fontSize: '32px', fill: '#fff'});

        //Rotation of the player
        if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.player.angle > -45) {
            this.player.angle -= 1;}

        if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.player.angle < 0) {
            this.player.angle += 1;}

        //Shooting with the spacebar
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)) {

            //Animate the shooting
            this.player.anims.play('shoot', true);

            //Arrow shooting
            let arrow = this.physics.add.sprite(this.player.x, (this.player.y + 20), 'arrow');
            arrow.enableBody = true;
            arrow.body.immovable = false;

            //Edit arrow hitbox 
            arrow.setSize(50, 15).setOffset(5, 50);

            arrow.setGravityY(3600); //Gravity will affect the arrows

            //Arrow speeds
            arrow.setVelocityX(arrowMoveAmt);
            arrow.setVelocityY((this.player.angle * 50));

            this.arrows.push(arrow); //Add arrow to the arrow created earlier
            this.arrowSound.play(); //Play the sound

        }

        else if( this.target.body.touching.left) {

            let i = 0;

            //Set initial position of new medals
            let arrowOnTargetPositionX = 200;

            //Loop to create multiple arrows
            while (i < this.arrows.length) {
                newArrows = this.arrows[i];
                newArrows.setGravityY(0);
                newArrows.setVelocityX(0);
                newArrows.setVelocityY(0);

                //Add 30 to the new medal's x position
                arrowOnTargetPositionX = arrowOnTargetPositionX + 40;

                //Call the function to determine medal and pass the variable
                if(this.arrows.length <= 5) {
                    getMedal(arrowOnTargetPositionX);
                }

                i++;
            }
        }

        getMedal = (value) => {
            //Gold medal
            if (410 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 435) {
                this.add.image(value, 170, 'gold_medal');
                score += 5;
                this.player.angle = 0;
            }
            //Silver medal
            else if (395 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 450) {
                this.add.image(value, 170, 'silver_medal');
                score += 3;
                this.player.angle = 0;
            }
            //Bronze medal
            else if (380 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 460) {
                this.add.image(value, 173, 'bronze_medal');
                score += 1;
                this.player.angle = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    function render() {
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect it to show the score, with only one set of text, rather than pasting over the "SCORE: 0" over and over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the solution:

- **First**, set the **score variables** outside of the **`update()`** method, you should set them before the **`preload()`** function.
- **Second**, add **`scoreBoard = this.add.text(440, 40, "SCORE: 0", {fontSize: '32px', fill: '#fff'});`** in the **`create()`** method.
- **Third**, set **`scoreBoard.setText('Score: ' + score)`** after the last **`else if`** statement inside the **`getMedal()`** function.

The final code would be like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Configurations for the physics engine
    var physicsConfig = {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: false //CHANGE THIS TO TRUE TO SEE LINES
        }
    }
    //Configurations for the game itself
    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        physics: physicsConfig,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update,
            render: render
        }
    };

    //Declare  score variables
    let score = 0;
    let scoreBoard;

    //Start the game
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {   
        //Images
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/images/sky.png');
        this.load.image('target', 'assets/images/target.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/images/ground.png');
        this.load.image('arrow', 'assets/images/arrow.png');
        this.load.image('gold_medal', 'assets/images/goldmedal.png');
        this.load.image('silver_medal', 'assets/images/silvermedal.png');
        this.load.image('bronze_medal', 'assets/images/bronzemedal.png');
        //Spritesheets
        this.load.spritesheet('archer', 'assets/spritesheets/archer_sprites.png', {frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128});
        this.load.spritesheet('rings', 'assets/spritesheets/rings_sprite.png', {frameWidth: 320, frameHeight: 320});
        //Audio
        this.load.audio('arrow_shot', 'assets/sounds/arrow_shooting.mp3');
    }
    function create ()
    {   
        //Load all the images that won't move
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
        this.add.image(210, 200, 'ground');

        //Create the archer/player
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 410, 'archer');
        this.player.setBounce(0.2);
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

        //Shooting animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'shoot',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('archer', {start : 0, end: 4}),
            frameRate: 20,
            repeat: 0
        });

        //Rings animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'rings_anim',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('rings', {start : 0, end : 69}),
            frameRate: 10,
            repeat: 0
        })
        //Play the animation on start
        this.rings = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 40, 'rings');
        this.rings.anims.play('rings_anim', true);

        //Create the target
        this.target = this.physics.add.sprite(530, 365, 'target');
        this.target.setSize(115, 95).setOffset(70, 130); //TARGET HITBOX
        this.target.enableBody = true;
        this.target.setImmovable();

        //Create an array for arrows for later
        this.arrows = [];

        //Create an array for medals for later
        this.medals = [];

        //Get keypresses
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        //Assign input for spacebar
        this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

        //Play sound when the arrow is shot
        this.arrowSound = this.sound.add('arrow_shot');

        //Make the arrows collide with the target
        this.physics.add.collider(this.arrows, this.target)

        //Add the scoreboard in
        scoreBoard = this.add.text(440, 40, "SCORE: 0", {fontSize: '32px', fill: '#fff'});

    }
    function update ()
    {   
        //Declare constants for movement
        const playerMoveAmt = 200;
        const arrowMoveAmt = 1500;
        this.player.setDrag(2000);

        //Rotation of the player
        if (this.cursors.up.isDown && this.player.angle > -45) {
            this.player.angle -= 1;}

        if (this.cursors.down.isDown && this.player.angle < 0) {
            this.player.angle += 1;}

        //Shooting with the spacebar
        if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar)) {

            //Animate the shooting
            this.player.anims.play('shoot', true);

            //Arrow shooting
            let arrow = this.physics.add.sprite(this.player.x, (this.player.y + 20), 'arrow');
            arrow.enableBody = true;
            arrow.body.immovable = false;

            //Edit arrow hitbox 
            arrow.setSize(50, 15).setOffset(5, 50);

            arrow.setGravityY(3600); //Gravity will affect the arrows

            //Arrow speeds
            arrow.setVelocityX(arrowMoveAmt);
            arrow.setVelocityY((this.player.angle * 50));

            this.arrows.push(arrow); //Add arrow to the arrow created earlier
            this.arrowSound.play(); //Play the sound

        }

        else if( this.target.body.touching.left) {

            let i = 0;

            //Set initial position of new medals
            let arrowOnTargetPositionX = 200;

            //Loop to create multiple arrows
            while (i < this.arrows.length) {
                newArrows = this.arrows[i];
                newArrows.setGravityY(0);
                newArrows.setVelocityX(0);
                newArrows.setVelocityY(0);

                //Add 30 to the new medal's x position
                arrowOnTargetPositionX = arrowOnTargetPositionX + 40;

                //Call the function to determine medal and pass the variable
                if(this.arrows.length <= 5) {
                    getMedal(arrowOnTargetPositionX);
                }

                i++;
            }
        }

        getMedal = (value) => {
            //Gold medal
            if (410 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 435) {
                this.add.image(value, 170, 'gold_medal');
                score += 5;
                this.player.angle = 0;
            }
            //Silver medal
            else if (395 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 450) {
                this.add.image(value, 170, 'silver_medal');
                score += 3;
                this.player.angle = 0;
            }
            //Bronze medal
            else if (380 < newArrows.y && newArrows.y < 460) {
                this.add.image(value, 173, 'bronze_medal');
                score += 1;
                this.player.angle = 0;
            }
            scoreBoard.setText('Score: ' + score)
        }
    }

    function render() {
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

The **OP** asked me to fix an extra issue with the ***score amount*** which was not displaying the ***right score***. I fixed it by removing the **`getMedal()`** function & its **`if` statement** wrapper outside of **`while`** loop like so:

```
//Loop to create multiple arrows
while (i < this.arrows.length) {
    newArrows = this.arrows[i];
    newArrows.setGravityY(0);
    newArrows.setVelocityX(0);
    newArrows.setVelocityY(0);

    //Add 30 to the new medal's x position
    arrowOnTargetPositionX = arrowOnTargetPositionX + 40;

    i++;
}
//Call the function to determine medal and pass the variable
if(this.arrows.length <= 5) {
    getMedal(arrowOnTargetPositionX);
}
```

Comment: it displays correctly, however, the score does not go up like I thought It would. I need the score to go up 5 whenever a gold medal is added, 3 for a silver, and 1 for a bronze. (Ex. if you get 2 gold medals, one silver, one bronze, and you miss the last arrow, your score would be 14) The score does not behave this way. Where should I move the "score +=" statements?

Comment: @RobertSmith , I have updated my answer with the fixed score amount.

Comment: thank you again and sorry to keep bothering. But now, sometimes when I get two gold medals, the score won't change, or when I miss with an arrow, the score resets back to one. Do you know why this is? Should I just create an array for the medal objects and just use the array to determine the score?

Comment: and when you say you removed the "getMedal()" function, do you mean completely removed?

Comment: No,  I meant to take it off from the `while` loop along with its `if` statement. Just copy paste the last code snippet above  concerning the `while` loop.

Comment: @RobertSmith I just double-checked & it works when you follow the instruction above. Let me know, if you got any questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201164/discussion-between-robert-smith-and-manuel-abascal).